Syntax Highlighting C# Raw Strings for SQL
The raw string literal feature of c# seems very useful but I thought I would also get syntax highlighting especially for json objects and sql statements.
But with the visual studio 22 version 17.10.5 I don't get any syntax highlighting in raw strings.
So I would like to have syntax highlighting when writing sth like this:
"""SELECT * FROM mytable"""


It's not implemented yet, but it's planned
